# CNTK/Python: How to load the saved model from training_session/CheckpointConfig

Tags: python, deep-learning, cntk

I used [`CheckpointConfig`](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.train.html?highlight=checkpointconfig#cntk.train.training_session.CheckpointConfig) in [`training_session`](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.train.html?highlight=training_session#cntk.train.training_session.training_session), and it generated 2 files (model_file (without extension) and model_file.ckp). Then, I used [`load_model`](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.ops.html?highlight=load_model#cntk.ops.functions.load_model) to load the generated file (without extension).

Now, how can I use this loaded model to evaluate a new input?

```
loaded_model = load_model(model_path)
loaded_model.eval(test_x)
```

I tried above, but I got this error:

```js
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-92b81f195f09> in <module>()
      1 test_x, test_y = generate_minibatch((1, 128, 128), 1)
----> 2 pred = loaded_model.eval(test_x)
      3 
      4 print(pred.shape)
      5 

/root/anaconda3/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cntk/cntk_py.py in <lambda>(self, name)
   1341     for _s in [IDictionarySerializable]:
   1342         __swig_getmethods__.update(getattr(_s, '__swig_getmethods__', {}))
-> 1343     __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, Function, name)
   1344 
   1345     def _backward(self, state, rootGradientValues, backPropagatedGradientValuesForInputs):

/root/anaconda3/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cntk/cntk_py.py in _swig_getattr(self, class_type, name)
     81     if method:
     82         return method(self)
---> 83     raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (class_type.__name__, name))
     84 
     85 

AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

I confirmed that `load_model.eval(test_x)` works fine when I used `save_model`.

Comment: It would be helpful to know something about loaded model such as the output of `print(repr(loaded_model))`.